# SDL 8.5 Migration - publication target nodes

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5

we are migrating from 2013sp1 to 8.5.

in our website we have two locations for disaster recovery. This means that we have two broker databases and when a content is published, it's sent to two deployers that insert the content in both databases. In Tridion, we configured two nodes inside publication target.
How we can replicate nodes in SDL Web 8.5? we understand that we have to install two deployers but we don't know if we have to install two discovery services, only one, ...

Another doubt is which services we need to install only publication process. is it enough with Deployer and Discovery or we need another one? 
We are thinking to split publication process and CIS services for webapp in two machines and we can't find in documentation which services are needed for publishing when we split it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How we can replicate nodes in SDL Web 8.5?**
It is very much possible and you need to configure your discovery service to use a MIRROR strategy for deployment. You basically need to register multiple URLS in the discovery service. You can find documentation in the [FAQ link](https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/FAQ/000004163).

**is it enough with Deployer and Discovery or we need another one**

The core content delivery roles are discovery service, content deployer and content service (depending of how you want to retrieve your content). You may need an additional non-essential role like Context service if you choose to go with DXA. In general, it is preferred to keep the CD services in one box separated from the web application.The other advantage of this approach is that you can also minimize the CD licenses since your web application does not need any licenses anymore.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You will need 1 Discovery and Deployer service per environment. It sounds like you have 2 environments.  You will need both the Discovery service and Deployer service to enable publishing.  Also, from Web 8 and above, you will need to create a Topology in TopologyManager, and this is from the CMS, and will ask you to supply the Discovery Service URL.

It is common to place the microservices on one machine as a 'CIS Services' box.  The Publisher service (and the CMS install) can be on a separate box when scaling out publishing.

Comment: Thanks, @robotc. Your response is perfect but I only can accept one response :(.